# using pythagorean theorem to find point within a distance

Tags: php, mysql, math

ok i have a database that has 3 fields planetkey, xcoord, ycoord...

i want to find all the planetkeys within 30 of the location entered.. this is what i have...

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM adlplanet WHERE SQRT(POW(xcoord - 172.3900, 2) + POW(ycoord - 247.5000, 2)   < 30";  
$queryrow2 = mysql_query($sql2);        
while ($jumpl  = mysql_fetch_array($queryrow2)) {
        echo $jumpl['PlanetKey  '];
}
```

Comment: You're missing a paranthesis to close your SQRT. If that doesn't solve the problem, what other errors do you get?

Comment: And what's your problem? (Apart from a missing ')' for sqrt in the first line, I would guess...)

Comment: $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM adlplanet WHERE (SQRT(POW(xcoord - 172.3900, 2) + POW(ycoord - 247.5000, 2)) < 30";  no error... just nothing shows

Comment: @Lab: You are still getting an error since you introduced a new missing `)` to counter the one you added before `SQRT`...

Comment: sorry i just figured out what u were talking about... thanks.. it works now

Comment: Use this instead `SELECT * FROM adlplanet WHERE POW(xcoord - 172.3900, 2) + POW(ycoord - 247.5000, 2) < 900` No need for that SQRT.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is `(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = c^2`

So the 30 should be 30^2:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM adlplanet WHERE SQRT(POW(xcoord - 172.3900, 2) + POW(ycoord - 247.5000, 2)   < POW(30,2)";
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the extra ')' that was missing from the original post.